# Parsley.js pattern for Phone number and CNIC

Tags: validation, parsley.js

How to design your own parsley.js pattern? Like I want pattern for phone number and CNIC:
Phone number= XXXX XXXXXXX (0321 5464695)
CNIC= XXXXX XXXXXXX X  (38560 6665849 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by crafting your own validator.

As the [documentation refers](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-validators-craft), you can do something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="target">
    <input type="text" name="cnic" value="" data-parsley-cnic />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.ParsleyValidator
            .addValidator('cnic', function (value, requirement) {
                var patt = /^\d{5} \d{7} \d{1}$/i;
                return patt.test(value);
            }, 32)
            .addMessage('en', 'cnic', 'This value is incorrect');

            $("#target").parsley();
    });
</script>
```

You can see this working with [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TxE7/)